# Get span tags of a div

Tags: jquery, css, html, css-selectors

I have a table like this:

```
<div id="table">
  <div class="header-row row">
    <span class="cell primary">Team</span>
    <span class="cell">GP</span>
    <span class="cell">W</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="radio" name="expand">
    <span class="cell primary" data-label="Team">Real Klarin</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="GP">1</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="W">0</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="radio" name="expand">
    <span class="cell primary" data-label="Team">Cage</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="GP">5</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="W">4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

My overall goal is to print (in an iterative approach):
Real Klarin
1
0
Cage
5
4

So, I tried to collect all the spans for a start with this:

```
$('#table div span').each(function (index) {
    console.log(this); // "this" is the current element in the loop
});
```

but it prints HTML objects and `span` tags, which got me confused. Any ideas please?

---

EDIT:

```
console.log(this.textContent);
```

is an improvement, but now I am getting:
Team
GP
W
Real Klarin
...

How can I skip the first div? Or, in other words, how can I skip the div with .header-row?

Comment: `console.log(this.textContent);`

Comment: Thanks @Siguza, that was a good move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To skip the first div you need `:not` selector or `.not()` in js

```
$('#table div:not(:first)').each(function (index) {
  if(index == 1){  // index starts from 0 so for second record use 1
    $(this).find('span').each(function(){
      console.log($(this).text());
    });
  }
});
```

or

```
$('#table div').not(':first').find('span').each(function (index) {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: @gsamaras you're welcome .. you can read about [selectors here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

Comment: Thanks Yousef, but I would like to find a way to access a specific div, for example the second team, so I am looking up for `eq()` now!

Comment: @gsamaras for second team you can try  $('#table div:not(:first)').eq(1).find('span"first').text(); or you can use it without :not  ... $('#table div:eq(2)').find('span:eq(0)').text(); .. this more and more of ways :)

Comment: @gsamaras updated answer may help a bit  , Good Luck :)

Comment: @gsamaras Sorry about that you are free to use any structure you want but  I really wondered why you use divs and spans while you can make a structure easier by using table with rows and columns?? maybe you will need to make some sort for your visitors to get a top team or something like that

Comment: Because I found a ready responsive table with this structure! I just now trying to sort it...I was thinking of doing that with PHP, I am still looking..

Comment: @gsamaras this how table structure looks like .. http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/2yrdqyb6/4/  .. after dynamically generated elements your click and change events will no longer work so you should look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements .. Good Luck :)

Comment: You really put so much effort on that, but I have already started the sorting process in PHP, however, I will upvote another answer of yours I like.

Comment: @gsamaras believe it or not .. its not related with efforts or upvotes  .. its related to how to be helpful for someone need to help .. Thanks anyway and hope the code will be helpful for you .. again Good Luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
$('.row:not(.header-row)').each(function(){
    $(this).find('span').each(function(){
        console.log($(this).text());
    });                     
});
```

What it's doing is 'for each row that isn't the header row do this:'
'for each span within this, log its text (the text inside of the tag)

Comment: You foresaw my edit, who are you, Alakazam? :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead. You're logging the DOM element, and not the text pulled from a jQuery-wrapped dom element.

```
$('#table div span').each(function (index) {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Or instead of nesting loops, as in the case of an each inside an each, you could shift your selection strategy slightly. Looking at the target elements, I notice a common thread of having a custom data attribute (i.e. `data-label`); therefore, you could also make your selection like this:

```
// not selecting the header "cells"
$('#table [data-label]').each(function(i, el) {
  console.log($(el).text());
})
```

This is a more performant strategy than selecting and filtering dom in nested `.each()` calls.

Comment: Thanks Todd, but this won't skip the first div, as the other answer does, +1 though for pointing to the right direction.

Comment: @gsamaras no problem! I've added an alternative method you may appreciate, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the .text() method like this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#table div span').each(function() {
            var text = $(this).text();
            console.log(text);
        });
    });
</script>
```

More info: http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: Same comment as with Todd's, please read the other answers before posting.